# Index out of bound when looping over an array

Tags: python, arrays

I want to run the following code. Basically, I want to change the content of my `data` array until I get a certain result. To do this, I loop over the `subsequnce_to_map` to map array.

```
    data = [213, 33, 44, 12, 14 ... 14,76,99,102] # datapoint features
    subsequence_to_map = [918, 3, 44 , 65, 64 ... 23, 58, 111]
    i = 0
    j = 0

    while (misclassified == False):
        print("I enter the loop")
        if (data[j] != 0):
            data[i] = subsequnce_to_map[i]

            y_after = model2.predict(data)

            print("New classification approximation {}".format(y_after))
            j += 1
            if (np.round(y_hat) != np.round(y_after)):
                misclassified = True

        if (i + 1 == len(subsequnce_to_map)) :
            break

        i += 1
```

Now I get the following error:

```
I enter the loop
New classification approximation [[0.03014901]]
I enter the loop
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/datadisk/Workspace/stat.py", line 119, in <module>
    main(config)
  File "/datadisk/Workspace/stat.py", line 95, in main
    if (data[j] != 0):
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

I know very well that both arrays are of the same size 100. I make sure of that earlier. However I get this error always on the 3rd loop. Can anyone help me troubleshoot?

The predict function is a keras predict function and model2 is a keras model but they should not be an issue.

Comment: The code shown in your traceback does not match the code you pasted here.

Comment: I fixed it, sorry, it was a bad copy paste

Comment: This code will not run as it is. Please create a [mcve] so that we can help you better

Comment: Additionally, after removing references to models, y-values, and `misclassified`, the loop works for me, and replaces all values in `data` with the same-indexed number from `sequence_to_map` (check your spelling on `sequence` in your code, as well, looks like a simple typo occurred twice)